# Can one prove that $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$ can only be a linear sum of the $4$ functions?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

I was recently wondering how many functions are there take the positive integers as inputs and follows the following property:

$$ f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$$

Here are some functions I could think of:

$$ f_1(x) = \ln(x)$$
$$ f_2(x) = 0 $$
$$ f_3(x) = \text{Number of primes of }(x)$$
$$ f_4(x) = \text{Sum of primes of }(x)$$

For example:

$$ f_3(75) = 1 + 2 =3 $$
$$ f_4(75) = 5+ 5+ 3 =13$$

with $f_3(0)= f_4(0) = 0$

### Question

Is it possible to prove any function with the property: $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$ can only be a linear combination of the functions $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ and $f_4$?

Comment: P.S: I only mentioned $f_2$ for completeness ...

Comment: What linear combination of these functions would equal $g(x) =$ the number of $2$s in the prime factorization of $x$?

Comment: Ah ... clever ... didn't think of that one :)

Comment: For factorization $x=\prod a_i^{k_i}$ function $f(a) = \sum k_i g(a_i)$ will work for any $g$. For you functions: $g_1=\log$, $g_2=0$, $g_3=1$, $g_4(k)=k$

Comment: For any such function $f$ and any solution $g$ to the [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), $g\circ f$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The positive integers $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ with multiplication are the free monoid on a countable set (the primes). Thus every map from this countable set to any monoid extends uniquely to a monoid homomorphism.

Your sought map is a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}$ (the codomain with addition). Indeed, $f(1)=f(1\cdot1)=f(1)+f(1)$ implies $f(1)=0$.

Thus you can define arbitrarily $f(p)=a_p$ on every prime $p$ and the function will be
$$
f(p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\dotsm p_k^{r_k})=r_{p_1}a_{p_1}+r_{p_2}a_{p_2}+\dots+r_{p_k}a_{p_k}
$$
Your case 1 is with $a_p=\ln p$; case 2 is $a_p=0$; case 3 is with $a_p=1$; case 4 is with $a_p=p$ (in all cases, “for every prime $p$” is implied).

You can “count the $2$’s” by setting $a_2=1$ and $a_p=0$ for every $p\ne2$. This function is not a linear combination of the ones you mention.

Comment: Can you clarify how this answers the question? You seem to have characterized the multiplicative functions, but I don’t see where you have addressed the OP’s question as to whether all these functions are linear combinations of the specific four functions listed in the question.

Comment: @SteveKass It's quite easy to show they *aren't*. It was already commented in this sense. Anyway, I added a final suggestion.